# Execute Java Jar from Windows Command with External Properties file on C drive

Tags: java, jar, properties, command

I would like to know how to include a path to my properties files in the Windows Command line so that my JAR file will execute.

Jar/Command Line: `java -jar Parser.jar` 
Properties File: `C:\Properties\Parser.properties`

I've tried, from another article:

```
java -jar Parser.jar -Dconfig=C:\Properties\Parser.properties
```

But that results in:

```
Exception during initialize() java.io.FileNotFoundException: Parser.propertie
s (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Parser.properties (The system cannot find the
file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.system.tools.parser.ParserMain.initialize(Parser
Main.java:100)
        at xxx.xxx.xxx.system.tools.parser.ParserMain.main(ParserMain.j
ava:55)
```

Comment: If the property file is picked from the classpath, just adding to the classpath should work fine. java -classpath "C:\Properties\Parser.properties" -jar Parser.jar

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my end. I moved the properties file to the same directory as the jar file and it worked. i.e. Jar was in C:\Parser\, so I moved the properties file to C:\Parser\ and that was it... :)